# time.perf_counter only shows units like 37724.0057971 seconds in Python

Tags: python

My code is:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, cpu_count
import time


def counter(num):
    count = 0
    while count < num:
        count += 1

def main():
    a = Process(target=counter, args=(500,))
    b = Process(target=counter, args=(500,))

    a.start()
    b.start()

    a.join()
    b.join()

    print("finished in", time.perf_counter(), " seconds.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

it takes under 1 sec yet some weird number of seconds is displayed.
I tried it with 1 billion and still got some random number like 377724.5675..,
As far as I know perf_counters shows time in seconds, but here I am confused. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`time.perf_counter()` starts from an arbitrary point in time, but counts in seconds.

If you're looking for time elapsed, keep track of the start time, then compute a duration.

```
start_time = time.perf_counter()
# ... do work ...
end_time = time.perf_counter()
duration = end_time - start_time
```

Comment: I saw someone do it like this and it worked. Maybe they changed how it works? Anyway, your way worked as well. Thanks.

Comment: They may have been working on a platform where `perf_counter` is initialized per-process.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck on the same tutorial and in fact it was giving me same random numbers when function time.perf_counter() was just just like above in print statement.

However changing the code to shown above:

```
start_time = time.perf_counter()
end_time = time.perf_counter()
duration = end_time - start_time
```

is giving me scientific notation of numbers like 7.000000533435e-07 (which didnt correspond to elapsed seconds at all).

If you want the result to be shown in seconds i came with other solution and it works weird,it's giving aproximetly 7 seconds all the time instead of real time

```
time_elapsed = (time.process_time_ns() / 10000000)
    print("It goes: ",time_elapsed, "sec")
```

success with further BroCode YT video :)